# SQL Right outer join with no match in right table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it anyhow possible to do a SQL query where you take some info from left table and all info from right table matching the conditions.
BUT if there is no records matching the conditions in the right table, it should still show the full record, but filled with a lot of *NULL*s

At the moment, I have come to this:

```
select
 u.id, u.fullname,
 r.*
from
 users as u
right outer join
 rapports as r
on
 u.id = r.userid
where
 u.active = 1
 and (r.closed = 0 or CONVERT(varchar, r.periodstart, 112) = convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112))
order by
 u.fullname
```

But this only shows records from `user-table` if there is a record in `rapports-table` matching the `WHERE`-conditions.

Is it anyhow possible?

Comment: If you want tables from the left (first) table, you should be using a LEFT outer join. I very rarely see right outer joins in practice because they're quite unintuitive to think about logically. IMHO.

Comment: True, but this still doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice where the conditions for the outer table (r) go - not in the WHERE clause (which converts your outer join to an inner join) but rather in the ON clause.

```
select
 u.id, u.fullname,
 r.*
from
 users as u
left outer join
 rapports as r
on
 u.id = r.userid
 and (r.closed = 0 
   or CONVERT(varchar, r.periodstart, 112) = convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112))
where
 u.active = 1
order by
 u.fullname;
```

However this is much better:

```
select
 u.id, u.fullname,
 r.*
from
 users as u
left outer join
 rapports as r
on
 u.id = r.userid
 and (r.closed = 0 or CONVERT(DATE, r.periodstart) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
where
 u.active = 1
order by
 u.fullname;
```

Answer (score 1):

**YES!**

Change `right outer join` by `left outer join`:

```
select
 u.id, u.fullname,
 r.*
from
 users as u
left outer join
 rapports as r
on
 u.id = r.userid
where
 u.active = 1
 and (r.closed = 0 or CONVERT(varchar, r.periodstart, 112) = convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112))
order by
 u.fullname
```

---

> The Left Outer Join logical operator returns each row that satisfies
>   the join of the first (top) input with the second (bottom) input. It
>   also returns any rows from the first input that had no matching rows
>   in the second input. The nonmatching rows in the second input are
>   returned as null values. If no join predicate exists in the Argument
>   column, each row is a matching row.

With this in mind, the `join` is made with the restriction `u.id = r.userid`. So, if the `where` restrictions didn't exist, the result would be the `u.id, u.fullname, r.*` for all `users`!

Since there's a `where` clause, some of the rows might be put ouside, if you don't want that, use this query:

```
select
 u.id, u.fullname,
 r.*
from
 users as u
left outer join
 rapports as r
on
 u.id = r.userid and u.active = 1
where
 and (r.closed = 0 or CONVERT(varchar, r.periodstart, 112) = convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112))
order by
 u.fullname
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. It still only shows records where a matching records is found in the right table..

Comment: Check my revised answer and read all of it. If I'm missing something tell me. But your problem should be in the where restrictions or you forgot to put left instead of right in the code!

Comment: If you have both `u` and `r` mentioned in the `WHERE` clause, you may as well change `left outer` to `inner`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed. Well spotted! :D

Comment: @erizias AaronBertrand spotted the restriction in the where clause that was putting aside some of the results. Now do you understand why that happened?

Comment: Yeah I understood it :) Stupid mistake :)

Thanks for the answers, both of you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #temp_table_name

SELECT DISTINCT
        b.NAME ,
        q.valueI
FROM    #temp_table_name q
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT   NAME
                           FROM     ( SELECT    NAME ,
                                                valueI
                                      FROM      #temp_table_name
                                      INTERSECT
                                      SELECT    NAME ,
                                                valueI
                                      FROM      #temp_table_name
                                    ) a
                           GROUP BY a.name
                           HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
                         ) b ON q.NAME = b.NAME
```